# Use VBA to select Excel cell values conditionally based on cell format (cell background color)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

[image: 1]

i want to print value where background yellow is same as cell and background white is [0,0]
for this condition i want to get

[1,9],[0,0],[1,7],[1,6],[0,0],[1,4],[0,0],[1,2],[0,0]

I've written some code

```
        Dim isect As Range
        Set isect = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("$B$80:$J$80"))
        If Not isect Is Nothing Then
                       
               Dim s As String
               If Target.Interior.Color = vbYellow Then
                s = Target.Value
                Else
                s = "[0,0]"
                End If
               Range("D96").Value = s
```

but it get only one value, what I should do for continuing.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use a loop over each of the cells in `Target`?

Comment: may you please expand ??

Comment: `Dim cell As Range`, `For Each cell In Target`....

Comment: sorry i can't got it , please help me

Comment: Two questions. **1.** Why `Intersect(Target, Me.Range("$B$80:$J$80"))`? Where are you calling the above code from? **2.** Are these normal colors or conditional formatting colors?

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim isect As Range
Dim aCell As Range
Dim Output As String

Set isect = Intersect(target, Me.Range("$B$80:$J$80"))

If Not isect Is Nothing Then
    For Each aCell In isect 
        If aCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow Then
            Output = Output & "," & aCell.Value
        Else
            Output = Output & "," & "[0,0]"
        End If
    Next aCell
    Range("D96") = Mid(Output, 2)
End If
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: The will overwrite the original cell values. The output has to be in `Range("D96").Value` :)

Comment: swap the line cell.value = s back to Range("D96").value  but then you will only have one cell with all the result sin and you'll only be able to see the last calculation?? Did you mean to put the answers in another range starting at D96 ?

Comment: No. I think you have misunderstood the question :) The output `[1,9],[0,0],[1,7],[1,6],[0,0],[1,4],[0,0],[1,2],[0,0]` has to be in Range("d96"). But then you may never know... I may have misunderstood the question ;)

Comment: you may have an extra , at the end but I'm checking I have the right idea ...

Comment: Yes you are close but this way you will have an extra "," in the end. Is it ok if I edit your answer?

Comment: yes of course edit it if you want  . just use a Rtrim to snip of the last ','

Answer (score 0):

### Dependent on Cell Property (Fill Color)

**Standard Module Code (e.g. `Module1`)**

```
Option Explicit

Function getString(SourceRange As Range, _
                   Optional ByVal FillColor As Long = 0, _
                   Optional ByVal CriteriaNotMetValue As Variant = Empty, _
                   Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = ", ") _
         As String
    
    If SourceRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    ' Write values of range to array.
    Dim Data As Variant
    If SourceRange.Rows.Count > 1 Or SourceRange.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        Data = SourceRange.Value
    Else
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = SourceRange.Value
    End If
    
    ' Modify values in array.
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, Result As String
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data)
        For j = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
            If SourceRange.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color <> FillColor Then
                Data(i, j) = CriteriaNotMetValue
            End If
            Result = Result & Delimiter & Data(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
            
    ' Remove redundant Delimiter.
    getString = Right(Result, Len(Result) - Len(Delimiter))
    
End Function
```

**Sheet Code (e.g. `Sheet1`)**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const rngAddress As String = "B80:J80"
    Const cellAddress As String = "D96"
    Const CriteriaNotMetValue As Variant = "[0,0]"
    Const FillColor As Long = vbYellow
    Const Delimiter As String = ","
    
    If Intersect(Me.Range(rngAddress), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo clearError
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim Result As String
    Result = getString(Me.Range(rngAddress), FillColor, CriteriaNotMetValue, Delimiter)
    Me.Range(cellAddress).Value = Result
    
CleanExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
    
clearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    On Error GoTo 0
    GoTo CleanExit
    
End Sub
```